# On a side note vs. on a different note?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage, idioms

Is it grammatically correct if I write:

> On a side note, should I expect an e-mail/telephone call from you confirming my NHO date?
>   I am not sure if you are able to obtain/verify all the required information prior to my start day.

Comment: It's all perfectly grammatical - if that's what you need to know.

Answer (score 5):

Either "on a side note" or "on a different note" could be used here, and your sentence is grammatically correct. The difference is that "on a side note" implies a conversational shift to a related topic while "on a different note" implies a conversational shift to an unrelated topic.